# Algorithm to calculate percent difference between two blobs of text

Tags: python, algorithm, string

I've been researching on finding an efficient solution to this. I've looked into diffing engines (google's diff-match-patch, python's diff) and some some longest common chain algorithms.

I was hoping on getting you guys suggestions on how to solve this issue. Any algorithm or library in particular you would like to recommend?

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question. If you are looking at "longest common subsequences" and "diff" you know that it is a classical problem and NP-hard. No one here is going to do better than a few generations of computer scientists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: How about DNA [exact] matching http://www.springerlink.com/content/k2uq2r0037105466/ ?

Comment: What do you want, "percent difference" (defined how?) or "longest common something" (something probably == substring; "chain"???) or both (they're not the same)? Give an example e.g. s1 = "thequickbrownfox", s2 = "thequickvrownfox", what output do you expect? To what use will you put the result? What research have you done, and what conclusions have you reached so far? Is this homework?

Comment: @john
s1 = "thequickbrownfox"
s2 = "thequickbrownfoxes"

output, similarity = 98% (difference = 2%)

no, this isnot for a hw, i'm working on it to integrate it into a wiki.

Comment: @colorful: How do you get difference = 2% by adding 2 characters to a 16-character string? I ask again: how do you define percent difference? If you want help and are not just stuffing about, please answer the other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what "longest common [[chain? substring?]]" has to do with "percent difference", especially after seeing in a comment that you expect a very small % difference between two strings that differ by one character in the middle (so their longest common substring is about one half of the strings' length).

Ignoring the "longest common" strangeness, and defining "percent difference" as the edit distance between the strings divided by the max length (times 100 of course;-), what about:

```
def levenshtein_distance(first, second):
    """Find the Levenshtein distance between two strings."""
    if len(first) > len(second):
        first, second = second, first
    if len(second) == 0:
        return len(first)
    first_length = len(first) + 1
    second_length = len(second) + 1
    distance_matrix = [[0] * second_length for x in range(first_length)]
    for i in range(first_length):
       distance_matrix[i][0] = i
    for j in range(second_length):
       distance_matrix[0][j]=j
    for i in xrange(1, first_length):
        for j in range(1, second_length):
            deletion = distance_matrix[i-1][j] + 1
            insertion = distance_matrix[i][j-1] + 1
            substitution = distance_matrix[i-1][j-1]
            if first[i-1] != second[j-1]:
                substitution += 1
            distance_matrix[i][j] = min(insertion, deletion, substitution)
    return distance_matrix[first_length-1][second_length-1]

def percent_diff(first, second):
    return 100*levenshtein_distance(a, b) / float(max(len(a), len(b)))

a = "the quick brown fox"
b = "the quick vrown fox"
print '%.2f' % percent_diff(a, b)
```

The Levenshtein function is from [Stavros' blog](http://www.korokithakis.net/node/87).  The result in this case would be 5.26 (percent difference).

Comment: That algorithm is O(MN) in both space (unnecessarily) and time. Stavros said he was using it to check words of average length of 8, a bit less than the OP's "anywhere between a paragraph to a page".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `difflib` and other common subsequence libraries, if it's natural language text, you might look into stemming, which normalizes words to their root form. You can find several implementations in the Natural Language Toolkit ( http://www.nltk.org/ ) library.  You can also compare blobs of natural language text more semantically by using N-Grams ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram ).

Answer (score 1):

Longest common chain? Perhaps this will help then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 0):

Another area of interest might be the Levenshtein distance described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).