# Calculate the greatest distance between any two strings in a group, using Python

Tags: python, difference

My question is how to calculate greatest distance between any two strings that correspond to a certain group. Each line in my file starts with a 'group number' followed by a long string. I want to know, for each group, what the greatest distance between any two strings in a group, for each group. Below is the kind of file I'm working with (the strings have been shortened). Notice the groups aren't necessarily in order, and some of my groups only have one string associated with them, so I would want to just skip over them (Group '3' in the below example):

```
 0 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACGCGUGGGAACGUACCAUUUGCUACGGAAUAACUCAGG
 0 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACGCGUGGGAACGUACCAUUUGCUACGGAAUAACUCAGG
 1 CGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGCAAUCUGCCCUGCACUCUGGGACAAGCCCUG
 1 CGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGCAAUCUGCCCUGCACUCUGGGACAAGCCCUG
 1 CGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGCAAUCUGCCCUGCACUCUGGGACAAGCCCUG
 2 GCCCUUCGGGGUACUCGAGUGGCGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGUGAUCUGCC
 2 GCCCUUCGGGGUACUCGAGUGGCGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGUGAUCUGCC
 2 GCCCUUCGGGGUACUCGAGUGGCGAACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGUGAUCUGCC
 0 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACGCGUGGGAACGUACCAUUUGCUACGGAAUAACUCAGG
 0 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACGCGUGGGAACGUACCAUUUGCUACGGAAUAACUCAGG
 3 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACAAAAAGGAACGUACCAUUUGCUACGGAAUAACUCAGG
```

I want to create something that will create an output that looks something like this:

```
 Group0 = 0
 Group1 = 1.2
 Group2 = 2.1

 Average = 1.1
```

This output would be giving me the group number and then the greatest difference for that group. And also the overall average of the greatest difference between all groups (again skipping over the groups with only one string associated with them):

My real file has about 5000 groups, and the strings I'm comparing are ~400 characters long.

I think I could start solving this by looking at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106994/algorithm-to-calculate-percent-difference-betweem-two-blobs-of-text), but I'm not sure how to only calculate percent differences for strings in the same group, avoid groups with only one string, and calculate the overall average percent difference for all the groups. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much for any ideas!

EDIT: Here are a few truncated lines from the file I'm working with. The 'group' numbers range from 0 to ~ 6000. The string of letters is actually 426 characters long. The file format is [number][a whitespace][string of letters][end of line character]

`7 UGGCGAACGGGUGAGUAAC

35 GUGGGGAUUAGUGGCGAAC

50 AAACGAGAUGUAGCAAUAC

82 GGAGAGAGCUUGCUCUCUU

479 UCAGGAGCUUGCUCCUGU

46 CGAGGAGCUUGCUCCUUU

24 AACUGGGUCUAAUACCUU`

Comment: I don't think you're asking about calculating the difference between strings at all - you know how to do that, from the Question you posted.   You are asking a more basic question of how to process a list of strings from a file, right?

Comment: Use Levenshtein distance between 2 strings and assign weight for each modification operation to 1. You will get some measure of how many chars need to be edited for 2 strings to be equal. Then you can take it as % of your string length.

Comment: yeah you probably want a levenstien distance ... thats the standard measure of how far apart 2 strings are ... `pct = levenstein_dist/word_length`

Comment: Can I use the levenstein_dist for more than 2 lines though? I thought it only worked when comparing 2

Comment: Ah - so one of your questions is "given a set of strings, what does it even mean to ask 'what is the percentage difference between all these strings?'?"  ... right?     Can you answer this question yourself: I think it depends on the problem you're solving.   I can't guess what you mean by "what is the percentage difference between these three strings?"

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yes! So if there are four strings in Group0, what is the percentage difference between these four strings? And then continue for each group with at least two strings to compare.

Comment: That's why I thought the other Question has some elements that might be useful, but it only works when looking at 2 strings.

Comment: Only you can answer the question "what is the percentage difference between 4 things?", based on what your situation says that it means.   Difference is fundamentally a two-parameter measure.   What are _you_ trying to measure?   For example, can you tell me what is the percentage difference between 10, 12, 13 and 18?

Comment: @GreenAsJade What I know is each string (regardless of group) is 400 characters long, so what I'd like to figure out is how similar the strings in a group are to each other. Perhaps for most groups, all strings are identical! Or perhaps they are very close (only differ from each other by 5 characters out of 400!). That's what I'm getting at, does that make more sense? I thought percent difference would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: So - would you find it meaningful to know "what is the greatest distance between any two strings in this group?".   Maybe that's what you're asking?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Oh, I like that, that's a good way to phrase it. I'm going to edit the question!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45556/discussion-between-greenasjade-and-jen)

Comment: I've rephrased the question, hopefully this makes what I'm asking for more clear. Thanks for the comments/help so far!

Comment: If your groups get large, you could evaluate BK Trees:
http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees

Comment: The actual correct way to solve this problem is to get a microscope and hire an undergrad student to compare each of the bases in some strands of RNA.

Comment: @CodyPiersall haha, well I'm a student so I'm on the right track maybe? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try to use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)'s SequenceMatcher from the standard library:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> from itertools import groupby, combinations

>>> def find_max_ratio(lines):
    lines = [row.split() for row in lines]  # the file should already break at each line break
    lines = [(int(row[0]), row[1]) for row in lines]
    lines = groupby(sorted(lines), lambda x: x[0])  # combine strings into their respective groups, sorting them first on int of first element
    group_max = dict()
    for group in lines:
        strings = list(group[1])  # need to convert group[1] from iterator into list
        if len(strings) > 1:  # if the number of strings is 1, then there is nothing to compare the string with in its group
            similarity = 1
            for line1, line2 in combinations(strings, 2):
                s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, line1[1], line2[1])  # need to compare second element in each list and exclude the first element (which is the group number)
                similarity = s.ratio() if s.ratio() < similarity else similarity
            group_max[line1[0]] = 1 - similarity  # gives difference ratio
    return group_max

>>> t = open('test.txt')
>>> print find_max_ratio(t)  # it appears that your examples don't have any differences
{'1': 0, '0': 0, '2': 0}
```

You can then calculate the average as follows:

```
>>> max_ratios = find_max_ratio(t)
>>> average = sum(max_ratios.values())/float(len(max_ratios))
>>> average
0.0  # there are no differences in your test data above
```

**EDIT: Writing to a file**

```
>>> output = sorted(max_ratios.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # sorting by descending ratios
>>> with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:  # a new file name
>>>     f.write('\n'.join([group + ': ' + str(ratio) for group, ratio in output])
                + '\n\nAverage: ' + str(average))
```

**EDIT 2: Adding minimum difference**

You can add the minimum difference into your result (here in the form of a tuple `(<max_difference>, <min_difference>)` like this:

```
def find_maxmin_ratios(lines):
    lines = [row.split() for row in lines]  # the file should already break at each line break
    lines = [(int(row[0]), row[1]) for row in lines]
    lines = groupby(sorted(lines), lambda x: x[0])  # combine strings into their respective groups, sorting them first on int of first element
    group_minmax = dict()
    for index, group in lines:
        strings = list(group)  # need to convert group[1] from iterator into list
        if len(strings) > 1:  # if the number of strings is 1, then there is nothing to compare the string with in its group
            max_similarity = 1
            min_similarity = 0
            for line1, line2 in combinations(strings, 2):
                s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, line1[1], line2[1])  # need to compare second element in each list and exclude the first element (which is the group number)
                max_similarity = s.ratio() if s.ratio() < max_similarity else max_similarity
                min_similarity = s.ratio() if s.ratio() > min_similarity else min_similarity
            group_minmax[index] = (1 - max_similarity, 1 - min_similarity)  # gives max difference ratio and then min difference ratio
    return group_minmax
```

Then you can find the respective averages like this:

```
>>> t = open('test.txt')
>>> maxmin_ratios = find_maxmin_ratios(t)
>>> maxmin_ratios
{'1': (0, 0.0), '0': (0, 0.0), '2': (0, 0.0)}  # again, no differences in your test data
>>> average_max = sum([maxmin[0] for maxmin in maxmin_ratios.values()])/float(len(maxmin_ratios))
>>> average_min = sum([maxmin[1] for maxmin in maxmin_ratios.values()])/float(len(maxmin_ratios))
>>> average_max, average_min
(0.0, 0.0)  # no differences in your test data
```

**Edit 3: Optimization Concerns**

Finally, in light of your last comment, I'm not sure if you will be able to optimize this function too much in its present form. If your computer can't handle it, you may need to process smaller chunks of text and then compile the results at the end. `difflib` doesn't require huge amounts of memory, but it DOES do a LOT of work. Your performance SHOULD be a lot better than mine (depending on your machine) because every line of mine was random. If your lines are more similar than dissimilar, you should do a lot better. Here are the results of cProfile on my machine for the following scenario (3.172 hours total):

```
text2.txt
- 9700 lines of text
- each line begins with one random number (1 to 10)
- each line has 400 random characters that follow the random number  # if your data is not random, you should do CONSIDERABLY better than this
```

Note that the majority of the cumtime (the total time for a given function and all functions below it) was spent in difflib, which is outside of your control with the present function. In fact, the rest of the function takes very little time at all.

```
4581938093 function calls in 11422.852 seconds

   Ordered by: tottime  # the total time spent in a given function, excluding time spent in subfunctions

ncalls  tottime percall cumtime percall filename:lineno(function)
81770876    8579.568    0   9919.636    0   difflib.py:350(find_longest_match)
-724102230  1268.238    0   1268.238    0   {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
4700900 874.878 0   1143.419    0   difflib.py:306(__chain_b)
9401960 160.366 0   10183.511   0.001   difflib.py:460(get_matching_blocks)
2060343126  141.242 0   141.242 0   {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
1889761800  110.013 0   110.013 0   {method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects}
81770876    32.433  0   55.41   0   <string>:8(__new__)
130877001   32.061  0   32.061  0   {built-in method  __new__ of type object at 0x1E228030}
81770876    29.773  0   29.773  0   {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
1   23.259  23.259  11422.852   11422.852   <pyshell#50>:1(find_maxmin_ratios)
49106125    21.45   0   33.218  0   <string>:12(_make)
9401960 20.539  0   10239.234   0.001   difflib.py:636(ratio)
335752019   17.719  0   17.719  0   {len}
9401960 17.607  0   30.829  0   {_functools.reduce}
4700900 16.778  0   49.996  0   {map}
230344786   16.42   0   16.42   0   {method  __contains__' of 'set' objects}
191093877   14.962  0   14.962  0   {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
98214517    13.222  0   13.222  0   difflib.py:658(<lambda>)
4700900 6.428   0   6.428   0   {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
4700900 5.794   0   5.794   0   {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
4700900 5.339   0   1148.758    0   difflib.py:261(set_seq2)
4700900 4.333   0   1160.351    0   difflib.py:154(__init__)
4700900 3.83    0   1156.018    0   difflib.py:223(set_seqs)
4700900 3.43    0   3.43    0   difflib.py:235(set_seq1)
9401960 3.162   0   3.162   0   difflib.py:41(_calculate_ratio)
9700    0.003   0   0.003   0   {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
1   0.003   0.003   0.003   0.003   {sorted}
9700    0.001   0   0.001   0   <pyshell#50>:3(<lambda>)
1   0   0   11422.852   11422.852   <string>:1(<module>)
1   0   0   0   0   {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

If your machine can handle it, I would just run this function and be prepared to wait two or three hours. A LOT is happening here in order to compare these strings character-by-character.

Comment: Thanks for this! Sorry if this is a dumb question, but in the last line, where it says `print find_max_ratio(t)` would I need to set `t` to be equal to the file I'm working with?

Comment: @Jen I updated the function above slightly (in order to work with an opened file). I have also opened a file t (open('test.txt').readlines()) before calling the function with t as an argument.

Comment: Thanks! When I type `t = open('test.txt', 'w').readlines()` line (don't worry I remembered to change the file name haha!) I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: File not open for reading`

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but how could I send this output to a new text file? Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm! I have one last question, and if this should be a new question I'll post it (and sorry!), but if I wanted to change the function `find_max_ratio(lines)` so that it could find the minimum ration (so then I could have a range for each of my groups), would it be these 2 lines that I'd need to work on? `similarity = s.ratio() if s.ratio() < similarity else similarity` and `group_max[line1[0]] = 1 - similarity`

Comment: I skipped ahead to the average part, but when I just type in this line `print find_max_ratio(t)` all the ratios are coming up as 0.5 `'1866': 0.5, '4024': 0.5, '4025': 0.5, etc.`, do you know what that might be happening?

Comment: This is great, thank you! The input is in the form of `0 GCAGACGGGUGAGUAACGCGUGGGAACGUACC` (though the string of letters is about 400 long). Also, a group number could come up again later in the file (so 3 lines with group zero at the beginning but than about her group zero later on). Would that impact anything? Thanks for checking this out again!

Comment: @Jen I noticed that some of your lines have a space in front of them, so I added `.strip()`. Also, the format you mention should not impact anything. Let me know if you have further trouble.

Comment: Wow, thank you yet again! I tested these on small samples of a file I want to work with (about 10 lines) and they work perfectly! I just had two more questions for you if that's okay: 1. How could I find the average of the minimum difference, I tried to make one for the new `find_maxmin_ratio` function based off what you did: `>>> min_ratios = find_maxmin_ratios(t)
>>> average = sum(find_maxmin_ratios.values())/float(len(find_maxmin_ratios))` but no luck for me!

Comment: and sorry last question! 2. When I use these AMAZING :D functions on my whole file, python seems to freeze (white square of death!) I think it's because the file is 9700 lines long (probably too long)- so should I chop the file into smaller pieces and then use the functions on those, would that be my best bet?

Comment: @Jen I updated Edit 2 to indicate how to obtain max and min averages. I am in the process of testing the function on the size of file that you mention, but it may take a while. I'll post an optimization once the test finishes.

Comment: @Jen I added a third edit. If your machine can handle it at all, I would run the function all at once. The function won't require a lot of memory, but it will probably occupy entirely one processor on your computer for an hour or two, or perhaps even more. See above. `difflib` is the most demanding aspect of this function.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for walking me through the optimization! It looks like it takes my computer about 2.5 hours to do it. One weird thing happened, when I just put `maxmin_ratios`, I only get output for groups 1 through to 8, even though I know there are other groups (19, 300, 4567) that have more than one line and should be included in the output.

Comment: sorry, I get output for groups 0 through to 9. It's almost like it's grouping all the groups together based on the first number it sees (so 9, 90, 91, etc. would all be in the same group). I'm adding a truncated version of a few lines now! Thanks for looking at this again!

Comment: Thanks for looking at it again! It runs faster now, but I'm getting either 0 or 0.5 for everything (`'3111': (0, 0.0), '1472': (0.5, 0.5), '1470': (0.5, 0.5)`). This seems strange to me, I copied a few lines of my file into TextWrangler to look at any invisible characters that might be popping up but I'm not seeing anything, do you have any idea why it might calculating only 0 or 0.5? I really can't thank you enough for baring with met like this!

Comment: @Jen I updated the function, and it's working fine. I made two changes: (1) Most importantly, I changed `s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, line1, line2)` to `s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, line1[1], line2[1])`. You were always getting 0.5 because the `SequenceMatcher` was comparing lists `[group, sequence]` instead of just the sequence. Thus the group always matched in comparisons and the string never did (when compared as a whole). (2) I changed the group to an `int`. If you want to stick to strings, simply delete this line: `lines = [(int(row[0]), row[1]) for row in lines]`.

Comment: It works perfectly, and does exactly what I hoped it would! If there was a way to give you 10 check marks I would (if there is tell me), thanks so much :)

Comment: @Jen I'm glad it works for you! Best of luck on your studies.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq_file = open("sequences.txt", 'r')

# make an dict of groups, each group is a list of sequences in that group

groups = {}

for item in seq_file.readlines():
    (group, sequence) = item.split()
    try:
        groups[group].append(sequence)
    except:
        groups[group] = [sequence]

# measure the distance from every seq in a group to every other seq in that group,
# keep a record of the maximum found in each group.  (It doesn't matter that we 
# compare a sequence to itself during this process).

max_distances = {}
for group_num, group_seqs in groups.iteritems():
    greatest_distance = 0
    for seq in group_seqs:
        for other_seq in group_seqs:
            greatest_distance = max(greatest_distance, levenshtein_distance(seq, other_seq))

    max_distances[group_num] = greatest_distance          
    print "max for group %s is %s" % (group_num, greatest_distance)

# Average maximum distance, across the groups

max_distanace_list = max_distances.values()
av_max_dist = float(sum(max_distanace_list)/len(max_distanace_list))
```

... the link you provided shows how to do levenshtein_distance().

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, I got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "help.py", line 15, in <module>
    groups[group] = []   
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: For doing the levenshtein_distance(), would I be copying the code frm the other question? (I'm sorry if that's a dumb question, I'm new to python so I'm still learning how to extract what I need from other questions) :P

Comment: Ah - my omission, you need to convert the group from a string "1" to an integer 1.   I've edited it in...

Comment: Yes - without looking _too_ closely at it, it appears that you could copy the definition of levenshtein_distance directly from that answer.  You need to put it in your file before the stuff I showed you (so that the function is defined before it is used)   Don't copy past the end of the definition of that function :)

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks for all your help! I got another error with this line, and I tried to fix it using `float` but it didn't work, what do you think? `group = int(float(group))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: AM158981`

Comment: What is the error that you got from `group=int(group)` ?   If group is getting correctly split out from the item, int(group) should work.

Comment: oops sorry, here it is! `group = int(group)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AM158981'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45558/discussion-between-greenasjade-and-jen)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the percentage difference between two strings in the following way:

```
a="GCAUGC"
b="GCAACC"

differences=0

for i in xrange(len(a)):
    if a[i]!=b[i]:
         differences+=1

percentageDifference = 100 * float(difference)/len(a)
```

That is assuming the lengths of the strings are all the same which they seem to be from your example.

Now it depends on what you really mean by percentage difference between all strings in a group on what you want to do. You could for instance mean that you want to check the difference between every combination of two strings in the group and get an average.

The issue of only doing this for each group can be solved by pre-processing the data. If the data is like you show it then you could split each line on the space and use the group number as a key in a dictionary and append the string to a list which is the item. Something like:

```
groupDictionary = {}

groupStringPair = line.split()
group = groupStringPair[0]
stringToAdd = groupStringPair[1]

try:
    groupDictionary[group].append(stringToAdd)
except KeyError:
    groupDictionary[group] = [stringToAdd]
```

Then you will have a dictionary with keys for each group and a list of strings for each group as the items. If you want to ignore groups that only have one string then you can either delete them from the dictionary or ignore them. You could do this by:

```
for k, v in groupDictionary.items():
    if len(v)==1:
        del groupDictionary[v]
```

Comment: Seemingly I can't comment on others posts just yet but it would seem that you would want to calculate a few different measures of the average difference to give yourself a better understanding of the data. So as pointed out by GreenAsJade you could get the maximum difference. But you could also look at the minimum difference, the mean and the median of all the differences, and maybe even the mode. That might give you a better overview of the data rather than just a single number.

Comment: That's a good idea to get multiple points of information I'd like to understand as much as I can about these groups and the sequences (strings) in them!